# Scheme invalid application error

Tags: scheme, lisp

i am using compileonline to compile scheme scripts, here i have some super easy script that reports and invalid application error. Could You tell me what is wrong?

```
(define (nazwa a) (
(cond 
((= a 0) 2.0)
((= a 1) 5.0)
);cond
);nazwa

);define

(display (nazwa 0))
```

Full error code: gosh: "error": invalid application: (2.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrapped the `cond` expression in an extra pair of parentheses, which Scheme takes as a function application. So it takes the result of the `cond` (2.0 in this case) and tries to apply it as a function, which obviously does not work.

To be clear: the syntax of defining a function is `(define (function-name parameters) expressions)` - there are no extra parentheses around the function body.